# Rails: Show all associated records on a has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through

I'm building a guestlist app and I have defined both Guest (name) and List models - guests can have many lists and lists can have many guests. Both are associated in a has_many through association (after reading that HABTM associations aren't a good idea).

Here are my models:

```
class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :lists, through: :checklists
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :guests, through: :checklists
end

class Checklist < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :list
    belongs_to :guest
end
```

EDIT - my lists controller for show:

```
  def show
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
  end
```

On the List show view, I want to display the all of the guest names that are tied to that list through the checklist table. I can figure out if I need a do loop or an array...this is a bit beyond my current skill.

I've tried things like the following:

```
<%= @list.checklist.guest.name %>
```

I'm clearly missing some key bit of code and concept here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over guests like this:

```
<% @list.guests.each do |guest| %> # For each guest in list.guests
  <%= guest.name %> # print guest.name
<% end %>
```

Comment: You need to set `@list` somewhere in the controller. Can you edit your question and put the relevant code of your controller?

Comment: Are you sure that exist a list with the id? Aren't you passing the id of some guest or other model?

Comment: There is definitely a list as the page renders and returns simple things like the name of the list. I've placed in your code and it fixes the error on the page, but it doesn't actually render anything. This is the right direction, but I think it has to do with the has_many through association with the checklist table.

Comment: It does actually display an empty set of brackets...so it looks like it is trying to return an array, but it's empty. I'm going to check the database and make sure the associations are there.

Comment: Ok...figured out the issue...when I create a list and a guest, the associations aren't being written to the checklist table. I manually entered the data to test and a guest appeared. So thanks for the help on the iterate part. I should be able to handle the rest.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this

```
<% @list.guests.each do |guest| %>
  <%= guest.name %>
<% end %>
```